# How to call all of the methods of a group of objects created by the same constructor

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I am working on my javascript after a foray into the land of Java and have encountered a problem.  I have a constructor which gives each object the method this.move() and adds their names to an array.  I would like to call each of the methods this.move() that are held by the objects in the array but I cannot come up with a way to.  My code is below.

```
  var arrballs = [];
  var x;
  var y;
  var radius;
  var speed = 1;

  var startup = function startup() {
    var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    var ball_1 = new ball(5, 0, 100, 100, 2);
  }

  var ball = function(radius, heading, xposition, yposition, speed) { //constructor for balls
    this.radius = radius;
    this.heading = heading; //in standard polar
    this.xposition = xposition;
    this.yposition = yposition;
    this.move = function move() {
    this.xposition = Math.cos(this.heading)*speed + this.xposition  //converts the heading to a unit vector and multiplies it by the scaler speed value
    this.yposition = Math.sin(this.heading)*speed + this.yposition
    }
    arrballs[arrballs.length] = "ball_" + arrballs.length + 1;
    }

    function drawScreen() {
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        for (i=0; i<arrballs.length; i++) {
            arrballs[i].move();
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.arc(arrballs[i].xposition, arrballs[i].yposition, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();
        }
    }
```

Apologies for the spacing, it got eaten by the copypaste monster.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't get `arrballs[arrballs.length] = "ball_" + arrballs.length + 1;`. Why are you storing "*names*" of balls instead of the balls themselves?

Comment: Instead of doing `var ball_1` use an ARRAY!

Comment: I fell stupid asking this but how would I add code that adds the object to an array as a part of the constructor?

Comment: a) you shouldn't, better add it at the point where you call the constructor b) you have the object as `this` in the constructor, so you can do the same as you currently did with that string